# Setting UIButton highlighted title text against highlighted background producing dimmed text

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I have a custom, subclassed `UIButton.type = 'System'`.

It's embedded in a view with a blue background, which itself is in the main view of the view controller.

Button background color is set to white.

[image: button, default state]

I have the following code for the button subclass:

```
class CustomButton : UIButton{
@IBInspectable var highlightedBackgroundColor :UIColor?
@IBInspectable var nonHighlightedBackgroundColor :UIColor?
@IBInspectable var highlightedTitleTextColor :UIColor?
@IBInspectable var nonHighlightedTitleTextColor :UIColor?

override var isHighlighted :Bool {
    get {
        return super.isHighlighted
    }
    set {
        if newValue {
            self.backgroundColor = highlightedBackgroundColor
            self.setTitleColor(highlightedTitleTextColor, for: .highlighted)
        }
        else {
            self.backgroundColor = nonHighlightedBackgroundColor
        }
        super.isHighlighted = newValue
    }
}}
```

`highlightedBackgroundColor` is set to a `dark gray`.
`highlightedTitleTextColor` is set to `white`.

So, on press, button should show white title text on gray background. Instead I'm getting this:

[image: button, pressed]

It looks like the opacity of the title text color is < 100%; like it's being masked by background color or something else.

In IB, I've try adjusting all the drawing button settings, and also tried adding 'State config' settings, both in addition to, and in place of the setTitleColor code in the button subclass; nothing changes.

Any idea what to do to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the button type from 'System' to 'Custom' it should work.